# Quart.Net :Enable/Disable the job at RunTime

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net, ihostedservice, worker-service

i have done similar Thing in my Project https://andrewlock.net/using-quartz-net-with-asp-net-core-and-worker-services/. i am scheduling all the job at the StartAsync by fetching the job data from Db . My Requirement is I need to disable the job If Status Value is Inactive in Database at runtime and Enable if Status is Active. is there any way i can enable/disable the job at runTime. I know we have Scheduler.pauseJob ,UnscheduleJob . But i don't know how to implement at runtime.